# build thumbnail stripe in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, thumbnails

I'm trying to build a thumbnail stripe - I want to add images of 30x30 to the stripe dynamically as they are being lazy download from the source on the web.

For some reason, the images are being painted on the wrong width. I see them stretch on the whole stripe instead of staying 30x30...

I want the thumbnail stripe to be in the height of 40, and the width of 40xNum_of_thumbnails.

After each image is downloaded, I resize it to 30x30, and then I call this:

```
+ (UIImage *) addThumbImage:(UIImage *)thumb toStripe:(UIImage *)stripe atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake((index)*40, 40);
    if(UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL) {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO,  ([ UIScreen mainScreen ].scale));
}
else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
}

    // first, drawing the stripe we got till now
    CGPoint stripePoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    [stripe drawAtPoint:stripePoint];

    //now adding the new thumbnail
    //CGPoint thumbPoint = CGPointMake((index-1)*40+5, 5);
    NSUInteger locX = (index-1)*40+5;
    CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(locX, 5, 30, 30);
    [thumb drawInRect:newRect];

    UIImage* result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return result;

}
```

- I know that my images are correctly resized to 30x30 before I send them to that function
- I guess the problem is with the drawInRect somewhere... it draws it on the whole Image context.

EDIT: some more clarifications
the stripe is used to show thumbnails of photos in my app. It suppose to look a bit similar to what you can see in ipad's photos app. The reason I need to build it "on the fly" is because I have an unknown number of photos - it depends on something that is going on in the server side. Photos can be added or removed, so I need the stripe to be dynamic. Upon add/remove photo in the server, I will update the stripe in the app accordingly. 
I edited the code to include UIGraphic..withOptions and withoutOptions, and to add the right scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. thanks to @nielsbot I figured out what was wrong:
I had an IBOutlet for UIImageView which I put the thumbnail updated image inside.
But I never updated the size of the UIImageview according to the size of the stripe, so what happened was that the images got stretched... so simple and I missed it.

Thanks nielsbot. Thanks StackOverflow. you did it again ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
// I find this more convenient/readable than CGSizeMake:
CGSize size = { (index + 1) * 40.0f, 40.0f } ;
```

(If you think about the insert at index=0 case, with your code size will be {0, 40}). Also, why not make locX a float?

```
float locX = index * 40.0f + 5.0f ;
CGRect newRect = { { locX, 5.0f }, { 30.0f, 30.0f } } ;
```

So perhaps you have an off-by-one bug?

Comment: no that's not the case... I just tried changing my code with your suggestion - got the exact result. of course I also updated the index to get called with the right number. any other idea? :)

Comment: you need to pass a scale to UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions! It should be 1.0/2.0. You can use ([ UIScreen mainScreen ].scale)

Comment: If the stripe doesn't have any transparency, you can just use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()

Comment: finally--what are you using the stripe for? what's the maximum number of thumbnails? also, creating a new stripe image every time you add a thumbnail to it could be a performance problem. Could you create the stripe image in a single operation by having +(UIImage*)stripeImageWithThumbnails:(NSArray*)thumbs ?

Comment: @nielsbot - because you are really trying to help, I will edit my question to answer all your comments! thanks!

Comment: OK, I tried to change the scale, and to make UIGraphics without options... still doesn't work :(

Comment: Hm. How are you drawing the stripe on screen?

Comment: YOU ARE MY MAN!!! I had a IBOUTlet with uiimageview, but I never updated the size of the uiimageview, so it just stretched it on the screen... it must be that - I'm checking and updating :)